# How to keep a consistent value for iOS Storyboard object id

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard

I'm experiencing issue when merging branches in my iOS app. The storyboard object ID difference causes conflicts every single time. Is there anyway we can define constant values in the storyboard XML so that the object ID can be consistent ?

I've been trying to find the XML tag reference for storyboard but cant find any.

Any advice will be appreciated. Thanks guys!

Comment: This kind of conflict can take place when same UI elements are added to the same view controller on two different branches at the same time. As far as consistency of the UI elements in the interface builder is concerned, they do not change as long as you do not replace them with a new object.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Not sure why thats happening. I've never had an issue like that.

But you can add tags when you click on an object in storyboard(for example a button) go to its attribute inspector and under the "View" category, you can add a tag. Hope this helps.